# How to obtain sum of square of all cells in a column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In excel, my data is populated from Cell `B1` to `B10` in Excel. I want to obtain the sum of the squares from `B1` to `B10`.

I could use a simple function `POW(B1,2)+POW(B2,2)......+POW(B10,2)`. But this is too cumbersome to write and error prone.

Is there a shortcut function that is similar to `SUM(B1:B10)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use SUMSQ

```
=SUMSQ(B1:B10)
```

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. If your input numbers are in `B1:B10`, in `C1`, write `=POW(B1, 2)`
2. Then copy the formula in `C1` to `C2:C10`. This will automatically become `=POW(C2, 2)`, `=POW(C3, 2)` and so on.
3. Then take the sum of `C1:C10`